# WooCommerce: How to show attribute variation description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes

In WooCommerce under Products > Attributes > [Name of Attribute] > Add New [Attribute Variation] there is a section titled "Description" with the text "The description is not prominent by default; however, some themes may show it."

I'd like to show it in my theme directly below the attribute variation in the Additional Information tab. this is the code I currently have there. I'd appreciate any advice on how to get the attribute variation description to show just below the attribute variation.

```
<td><?php

  if ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] ) {

    $values = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute['name'], array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );

  } else {

    // Convert pipes to commas and display values
    $values = array_map( 'trim', explode( WC_DELIMITER, $attribute['value'] ) );
    echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );
            }
?></td>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [`term_description()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/term_description)

Something like the following should create a list of terms with their descriptions:

```
$values = wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute['name'], array( 'fields' =>  'all' ) );
if( $values ){
    echo '<dl>';
        foreach ( $values as $term ){
            echo '<dh>' . $term->name.' </dh>';
            echo '<dd>' . term_description( $term->term_id ) . '</dd>';
        }
    echo '</dl>';
}
```

Or if you don't want the description running through WordPress' default filters you should be able to just use `$term->description`.

Comment: That only outputs "<strong>:</strong>"

Comment: wc_get_product_terms must not be returning the term objects that get_the_terms does.

Comment: Turns out that it uses wp_get_post_terms which does return an array of objects.can you var_dump($terms) and add the result to your question?

Comment: Well it does if you tell it to return all the fields. I thought that was the default. See my edit.

Comment: It's worth noting that `term_description()` no longer takes a second parameter, which you can see at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/term_description/. Given that change the code should be written as `term_description( $term->term_id )` without `, $term->taxonomy`. It's also worth mentioning though that leaving the second parameter actually won't hurt anything for now.