# How to get the attribute description in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm editing the shop/archive page in Woocommerce. And to show attributes, I'm doing it with this code in functions.php:

```
function short_desc_product() {
    global $product;
    $product_type = $product->get_attribute( 'product-type' );
    $case_type = $product->get_attribute('case-type');
    echo "<div class='product-info'><p>{$product_type}</p> <p>{$case_type}</p></div>";
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'short_desc_product', 40 );
```

But I'm unable to figure out how to get the attribute description to show? get_attribute just gets the term title, but every attribute term has a description field. How do I access that?

Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps here? https://stackoverflow.com/q/32774652/367456

Comment: @hakre Thank you for the link. However, that deals with the single product page, it seems. And I have no idea how to edit it to show it on the Shop/Archive page instead?

Comment: the type of page should be regardless as long as you have the objects and then the objects of the attributes it looks like, doesn't it?

Comment: @hakre It doesn't show up. I've tried adding it with a function and add_action in functions.php. But it just shows up as text 'Array'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Its an array, when you echo it it will only show "`Array`". Look inside instead. Maybe `print_r()` sheds the information you're looking for: https://php.net/print_r